Why are modern, premium Android phones so much less secure than their equivilant iPhones?
The question is pretty much in the title.
As a long time iPhone user who switched to Android in 2022, and despite being happy with Android and not seeing myself return to iOS, the one thing that's dogged me is how poor the security is on Android phones vs. iPhones. Even when buying a flagship Android like the Samsung S24U, it's still no where near as secure as something like an iPhone 15.
You can see examples of this in things like the recently leaked support matrix slides that Cellebrite shows to their customers who are looking to crack into a phone. The iPhone matrix has far fewer vulnerable models and OSs than the Android matrix, which is almost literally green check-marks across the board.
Here are the documents in question for iPhones, and Android.
As you can see, a locked iPhone is pretty much down to brute-forcing even if it was never power-cycled, where as an Android that hasn't been power-cycled, but still locked, may as well have been left unlocked.
Why is this? Is this a hardware architecture difference? Is this a difference in how Android works vs. iOS?
What is it that makes a locked iPhone very difficult to break into, but an Android phone easy?

I'm wondering if [security.se] might be a better site for this question. Meanwhile, there are write-ups by GrapheneOS themselves on April 2024 leak and July 2024, which might clarify some matters or even give some hints to this topic. (I'm not an expert in security at all, so I better not to comment any interpretation of the writing)

Just consider how many Android manufacturer and models there are on the market and compare it with iPhone/iPad where there are just on manufacturer and a few models each year. Just by comparing this you will understand that the total number of devices doesn't matter. However what is true is that until recently the update support of Apple was far better than the one by Android manufacturer. But finally this is getting better even if the case of the phone of the Trump attacker shows that the time between discovery and fixing of a vulnerability is also important.

@Robert Again, even if we compare something like a Samsung S24U, vs an iPhone 15, both fully patched, the S24U seems to be more vulnerable than the iPhone.
We're not comparing some junky dollar bin phone to an iPhone. They are both flagship phones that are worth thousands of dollars, and this trend continues with every flagship Android based phone on the market.

@AndrewT. That write-up does seem interesting, and it seems like GrapheneOS has gone around the problem by way of rebooting the phone if it's been locked for more than a certain period of time, which is great... but the core problem still exists: Why can you, seemingly, dump the memory of a locked android phone and recover the devices encryption key from memory if it's been previously unlocked since boot, where as you can't on an iPhone, and why has no manufacturer addressed this yet?

After seeing how responsive the GrapheneOS team and their community were in the April 2024 discussion, I think it's a perfect time to join the July 2024 discussion and ask what you want to know, perhaps they may have the answer.

Android phones might appear less safe than iPhones because Android is open source and can be customized by many producers. So they have slower and inconsistent security updates compared to Apple. Also with Android users can install apps from outside the Play Store, and these are greater security risks. Of course Google has improved security with features like Google Play Protect but with such a diversity of devices it is way harder to maintain consistent security.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

This doesn't really address the question, and relies on several false pretenses. For one, Linux is open source, and perfectly secure, also the iOS kernel is also open source, and secure. In regards to side-loading apps, again they are supposed to be sandboxed, and while it's possible that they could break out of their sandbox, a locked device as used in my example should never allow app installation. It's a locked device.
